# Reset ColorOrder index for plotting in Matlab / Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have matrices `x1, x2, ...` containing **variable** number of row vectors.
I do successive plots

```
figure
hold all % or hold on
plot(x1')
plot(x2')
plot(x3')
```

Matlab or octave normally iterates through `ColorOrder` and plot each line in different color. **But I want each `plot` command to start again with the first color in colororder**, so in default case the first vector from matrix should be blue, second in green, third in red etc.

Unfortunately I cannot find any property related to the color index niether another method to reset it.

Comment: Do all the `x` matrices plot the same number of lines?

Comment: which version of Matlab do you use ? If you use version anterior to 2014b you can simply use `hold on` instead of `hold all` ... then all the `plot` command will start at the beginning of the colour order.

Comment: Actually I use Octave as I do not have Matlab license any more. @Dan I can imagine setting colormap of proper lenght, but unfortunately the number of lines varies. That is the reason for my question.

Comment: @Honza then you might have to loop. I'll edit my answer below to create a function for you...

Comment: A loop is not elegant but it seems to be the only way, unfortunately...

Comment: @Honza If you encapsulate it in a function, I don't see why it's not elegant to be honest. I highly doubt it will cause you performance issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can shift the original `ColorOrder` in current axes so that the new plot starts from the same color:

```
h=plot(x1');
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', circshift(get(gca, 'ColorOrder'), numel(h)))
plot(x2');
```

You can wrap it in a function:

```
function h=plotc(X, varargin)
h=plot(X, varargin{:});
set(gca, 'ColorOrder', circshift(get(gca, 'ColorOrder'), numel(h)));
if nargout==0,
    clear h
end
end
```

and call

```
hold all
plotc(x1')
plotc(x2')
plotc(x3')
```

Comment: It seems that this no longer works as of MATLAB 2020a. The answer from Luis Mendo using `set(h,'ColorOrderIndex', 1)` seems to work though.

Answer (score 18):

Starting from R2014b there's a simple way to restart your color order.

Insert this line every time you need to reset the color order.

```
set(gca,'ColorOrderIndex',1)
```

or

```
ax = gca;
ax.ColorOrderIndex = 1;
```

see:
http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/why-are-plot-lines-different-colors.html

Comment: This answer does not work in Octave, since ColorOrderIndex property is not used in octave.

Answer (score 5):

Define a function that intercepts the call to `plot` and sets `'ColorOrderIndex'` to `1` before doing the actual plot.

```
function plot(varargin)
if strcmp(class(varargin{1}), 'matlab.graphics.axis.Axes')
    h = varargin{1}; %// axes are specified
else
    h = gca; %// axes are not specified: use current axes
end
set(h, 'ColorOrderIndex', 1) %// reset color index
builtin('plot', (varargin{:})) %// call builtin plot function
```

I have tested this in Matlab R2014b.

Comment: Nice solution. I believe that it would work in current Matlab but unfortunately Octave does not know 'ColorOrderIndex' property.

Comment: Oh. Pity :-) I don't have access to Octave

Comment: Octave v5.1.0 does have `ColorOrderIndex`.

Answer (score 2):

I [found a link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/160332-rgb-values-for-2014b-default-colors) where a guy eventually solves this. He uses this code:

```
t = linspace(0,1,lineCount)';
s = 1/2 + zeros(lineCount,1);
v = 0.8*ones(lineCount,1);
lineColors = colormap(squeeze(hsv2rgb(t,s,v)))
ax=gca
ax.ColorOrder = lineColors;
```

Which should work for you assuming each of your matrices has the same number of lines. If they don't, then I have a feeling you're going to have to loop and plot each line separately using `lineColors` above to specify an RBG triple for the `'Color'` linespec property of `plot`. So you could maybe use a function like this:

```
function h = plot_colors(X, lineCount, varargin)

    %// For more control - move these four lines outside of the function and make replace lineCount as a parameter with lineColors
    t = linspace(0,1,lineCount)';                              %//'
    s = 1/2 + zeros(lineCount,1);
    v = 0.8*ones(lineCount,1);
    lineColors = colormap(squeeze(hsv2rgb(t,s,v)));


    for row = 1:size(X,1)
        h = plot(X(row, :), 'Color', lineColors(row,:), varargin{:}); %// Assuming I've remembered how to use it correctly, varargin should mean you can still pass in all the normal plot parameters like line width and '-' etc
        hold on;
    end

end
```

where `lineCount` is the largest number of lines amongst your `x` matrices

Answer (score 1):

If you want a slightly hacky, minimal lines-of-code approach perhaps you could plot an appropriate number of (0,0) dots at the end of each matrix plot to nudge your colourorder back to the beginning - it's like Mohsen Nosratinia's solution but less elegant...

Assuming there are seven colours to cycle through like in matlab you could do something like this

```
% number of colours in ColorOrder
nco = 7;
% plot matrix 1
plot(x1');
% work out how many empty plots are needed and plot them
nep = nco - mod(size(x1,1), nco); plot(zeros(nep,nep));
% plot matrix 2
plot(x2');
...
% cover up the coloured dots with a black one at the end
plot(0,0,'k');
```