# group-lines same color as scatter-groups

Tags: matlab, colors, grouping, scatter-plot

I am plotting a grouped scatter plot with different colors. I let Matlab decide the colors, and it uses a flat mapping into the (default?) colormap.

I need to use the **same colors** as in the scatter-group for the lines.

**However, the default `ColorOrder` of the lines is not the same as scatter's.** Hence, resetting the `ColorOrderIndex` does NOT solve the issue.

Currently I can produce the follwing:

[image]

with:

```
% Data
N  = 3;
T  = 5;
xm = [6.3327    4.5682    6.1398
    7.6289    5.4423   10.5246
    3.5362    6.2185    8.2151
    6.6572    9.4543    7.4266
    6.1138    8.6453    8.2044];
ym = [7     0     7
    11     0    55
     1     1    18
    14     6    12
     8     2    22];
lm = [6.8176    0.3609    6.9693
   13.0347    0.5587   62.4217
    1.6841    0.8237   19.6712
    8.0186    4.1533   13.2623
    6.1108    2.7716   19.5666]

% Scatter groups
g = kron((1:N)',ones(T,1)); %// '
hs = scatter(xm(:),ym(:),[],g,'filled');
hold on

% Poisson group-fits
[xmsorted,posxm] = sort(xm);
posxm            = bsxfun(@plus, (0:N-1)*T, posxm);
hl               = plot(xmsorted,lm(posxm));
```

I tried to get the `CDATA` from the scatter, and it's basically my `g` (group index), and used that to index directly into the default colormap, but it seems that scatters use a different colormap?

Comment: Your example requires toolboxes. Do any of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183701/reset-colororder-index-for-plotting-in-matlab-octave) help? [Luis' answer with the `'ColorOrderIndex'` axes property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30185215/2748311) may be the simplest.

Comment: @excaza Thanks for pointing out the tb dependency, I hardcoded the data. Thats exactly what I was saying about scatter using a different colormap, resetting the ColorIndex has no effect.

Comment: To those who marked duplicate: I do not think this is a duplicate of the linked question. This has nothing to do with `ColorOrderIndex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `scatter` scales to the `colormap` of the figure, rather than using direct indexing. So if `cm = colormap;` then

```
round(1:((size(cm, 1) - 1) / (N - 1)):size(cm, 1))
```

should return the indices within the colormap (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885847/get-colormap-color-for-a-given-value)). The default `colormap` is 'parula', so if `scatter` used direct indexing rather than scaling, groups would have very similar colors.

To make subsequent line plots use the colors of the `scatter`, you can use

```
cm(round(1:((size(cm, 1) - 1) / (N - 1)):size(cm, 1)));
```

to set the line colors for plotting.

Alternatively, you can change the `colormap` of the figure: assuming the color order is the default (i.e. new `plot`s get colors from `lines` in natural order),

```
colormap(lines(N));
```

where `N` is the number of groups, should make `scatter` and line colors match.

Comment: The solution is valid. Not following what you mean by: "this makes sense as with the default colormap of parula direct indexing would lead to very similar colors". Would also be nice to find a way to inherit colors from scatter and pass them to lines, instead of changing.

Comment: @Oleg I clarified (I hope) and added code for how to get the colors from scatter.